# Unable to connect my Nexus 7 to a PC

Tags: connection-issues, nexus-7, mtp

I searched a lot over the Internet and tried all the advice I found.

I have installed drivers from the ASUS site and changed `C:\Windows\inf\wpdmtp.inf` so it now contains

```
; Nexus 7
%GenericMTP.DeviceDesc%=MTP, USB\MS_COMP_MTP
%GenericMTP.DeviceDesc%=MTP, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E42&MI_00
```

both in `[Generic.NTx86]` and `[Generic.NTamd64]` sections.

My device is in MTP mode.

Computer sees it in PTP mode.

USB debugging is on.

It was said that I need Windows Media Player 11, but I have Windows 7 so it should be included, although I don't know where to check the version.

Here is what I see in device manager after all failed attempts:

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, MTP and ADB are incompatible.  Try turning USB debugging off, I've never been able to get it to connect right with it on.