# File transfer between Windows 8 and Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, mtp

I'm struggling with it for ages and I can't seem to get it working. Every solution on the internet just lets me to install ADB drivers. But besides of developing I'd also like to use my Nexus as a regular user, for example send some files from my Win8 PC to the tablet. Soe I'm enabling MTP.

But this is no-go. Nexus7 is displayed with conflict on the device manager. Automatic install won't install nothing. Drivers from asus website won't install (these are just ADB drivers). Basically no drivers I found over the internet won't install.

For god sake, it's world most popular Android tablet. Is it Windows 8 which is so retared?

MTP not recognized, PTP aswell. No drivers found anywhere.

EDIT:
I found a "solution" - it's called "Sell the bloody Windows machine and buy a Mac" - works like a charm. There is also another one I tested: "get back to Win7" worked too...

Comment: Have you checked for similar questions here? I recommend a [search for "nexus mtp windows"](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=nexus+mtp+windows), and go over the 24 results found. I'm pretty sure one of them will solve your question.

Comment: Please check: [Nexus 7 won't show up as a drive on Windows in MTP mode after update to Android 4.2](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35635/16575), [Unable to connect my Nexus 7 to a PC](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36157/16575), and [Problem connecting Nexus 7 as mass storage device on Windows 7](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/26689/16575).

Comment: None of this solves the problem. It's not like I've asked the question right away. But guess what. It all works like a charm on Windows 7

Comment: So it seems the culprit rather comes from Redmond. Not using anything from there for decades (I rawly remember the last Windows I used was some 3.11, then I jumped ship), I hardly can help you with that, sorry...

Comment: Have you tried going a different route and just use [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid)?

Comment: It's barely a solution - just a workarround. I've used another workarround which was geting rid off this horrid OS which Win8 is and got back to Win7

Comment: I agree. I hate Win8 (use it on laptop) but love Win7 (use on main computer). Still, I use AirDroid because I need to transfer even with a Mac. Wish I had a better solution for you.

Comment: The main disadvantage of this that the transfer speed is slow compared to usb.

Comment: Have you tried installing the drivers in windows 7 compatibility mode?