# How can I drag and drop files to Nexus 7 from a Windows PC?

Tags: nexus-7, file-transfer, windows

I have a Nexus 7 tablet and Windows 7 computer. I can see the tablet in the device manager as a Nexus 7. It shows up as nexus 7 when I view it on my PC as a drive.

When I drag a photo to the tablet from the pc, the photo file on the nexus 7 shows up there. I cannot view the photo no matter what I do on the tablet, it says 0 photos. I also cannot get any video file to play on the tablet after I drag and drop it.  No sign of it on the tablet, but I can see it in the folder on my pc.

I am using USB. This is so frustrating.

Comment: How are you trying to view the photo and video on the tablet? Are you using a file manager? Making sure you're checking the right folder?

Comment: i am just using the tablets built in apps.  gallery for photos and google play to try and watch movies.  nothing shows under personal videos. or in the gallery

Comment: What folder are you dragging them to? Make sure its Pictures

Comment: i have tried draggin photos to the file labled pictures and downloads.  movies to movies and video.  i see it transfering over but i cannot view anything on the tablet. they have to be on the tablet as when i look under setting, storage it shows 6.71 mb in pictures and videos.  so the pictures i transfered and video are there.  i have been trying at this for 3 weeks now.  i am spent!

Comment: Trying downloading a file manager like Astro or ES File Explorer for the Play store and viewing them through their, see what happens.

Comment: See also: [File transfer between Windows 8 and Nexus 7](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47316/16575)

Comment: I will try that when i get home.  i appreciate the tip!

Comment: Do you try to refresh the Gallery ?

Comment: Did you try using AirDroid for this? Works most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Please see that the photo and video formats are supported by default. Else you might need to install apps that are available in google play. Use a file manager to open the picture by browsing to the location. Once you open it, they might start appearing in the gallery automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you should try pushing them using adb

```
adb push name_of_the_files_or_directory /sdcard/pictures
```

Comment: I am not sure what that means?  sorry kind of computer stupid i am.  there is no sd card.  just a 32gb hard drive

Comment: that is the device partition where adb will push the file :)

Comment: i think i will just throw the tablet in the trash and get an ipad.  this is crazy. somthing as simple as drag and drop not working.  one photo something!!!!  dam google

Comment: FYI @user36205, you can't drag-and-drop files onto an iPad. You have to put all your files in one folder and then sync that folder using iTunes. Just so you know.

Comment: i know.  but it seems that itunes just works.  am i out to lunch here?  i try to drag and drop one picture.  i cannot see it anywhere on the tablet.  dowloads no.  gallery? no.  it has been a very frustrating 3 weeks.

Comment: Matt it might be useful if you post a link to what and is, most users won't have heard of it.

Comment: Is this adb thing rooting or something like that?  i am using a stock nexus 7 32gb.  no modifications.  also when i use apps to play videos (MX Player) it cannot see the files i supposedly have transfered to the tablet.

Comment: @user36205 Nope it's a program that you run on your PC that lets you talk to Android devices via the command line, here's a link: http://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/ However you shouldn't need it for something like dragging/dropping which I know works.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app that allows you to drag & drop file by Wifi and should be easier to show picture and play movie on your device : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.filesdnd

It's "free" (with some limitation) on Android, and totally free on Pc and Mac.
There is a paid version without any limitation on Android (you can buy it by in-app payment). Basically you just need to install the app on your Android device and the software from the website : http://www.filesdnd.com on your computer.

Then drag your files on your device (the device must be on the wifi network), and with the paid version of the Android app, it will open automatically. With the free version, it will save it on your device, and then the file will be displayed in the left pane of the Android app.

If you don't have any application that can read your file, there will be a toast that will say it. Then you can uses application like DicePlayer for the movie, or QuickPic for the picture !

Comment: Comment from "anonymous" (invalid edit): *This app is not FREE, as you can only download 5 files per day, before you have to buy it.*

Answer (score 0):

[Airdroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/airdroid-best-device-manager/com.sand.airdroid) is a first of its kind to do this hassle free... I used to just use a file sharing application like [ES File Explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/es-file-explorer-file-manager/com.estrongs.android.pop) and choose "Cloud" – but *AirDroid* is a better choice if you want more freedom.

Answer (score -1):

[AirDroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/airdroid-best-device-manager/com.sand.airdroid) is great for that. I personally use it for everything. You can drag and drop files from desktop to your Android, or vice versa. You can access or modify clipboard, you can view your file browser, music player, you can send SMS, track your device and more.

Comment: While admittedly *Airdrod* is great: does it work via USB? OP is asking about the USB connection. Maybe he's got no WiFi in the place. Using mobile data just to be able to use *Airdroid* might not be an appropriate alternative then :)

Answer (score -1):

I know this sounds extremely basic, but...I could not drag and drop either. But cut and paste worked for me, as long as I had one window open (wouldn't work with 2).